# How to send a data parameter to a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have one component that takes a string as input. In one of its instances, I'm sending it a string literal; and to the other one, I want to send a data parameter. How can I achieve this?

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <HelloWorld msg="What's up, man?" />
    <HelloWorld msg="{{message}}" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Nothing much, doing OK"
    }
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>
```

HelloWorld

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>
```

This is what I get as a result:
[image]

Any ideas? Where am I going wrong? I have looked at similar questions, but I couldn't find anything concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`v-bind` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) is used to bind data properties:

```html
<HelloWorld v-bind:msg="message" />

<!-- OR shorthand -->
<HelloWorld :msg="message" />
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/data-binding-in-vue-xx98g?file=/src/App.vue:60-94)